# This function checks if username is already in database but i get error of UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sqlite

This function is supposed to check if the username I insert already exists in my database, but every time I create an new account and run the function an error of "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment" why?

```
def Check(userName, Password):
    c.execute("SELECT userNames FROM userInformation WHERE(userNames = ?)",
              (userName,))
    R = c.fetchall # Allow C.fetchall to populate other processes
    for row in R():
            print(row)
    if row[0] == userName:
            login_screen()
    else:
            Create_Data_entry(userName, Password)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This code would not even run.

Comment: I'm guessing (pending fixing the indentation like @Daniel says) that because if `R()` returns an empty iterable, `r` never ends up bound which would normally cause a `NameError`- however, since it's named inside a function, you'll get an `UnboundLocalError` instead.

Comment: Why do you need to test `if row[0] == userName`? The SQL query already performs that check, so how can the test fail?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does lots of unnecessary things.

First, there's no need to test if `row[0] == userName`, since the SQL query only returns rows where that's true.

Second, assuming `userNames` is a unique key in the `userInformation` table, there's no need to loop over the rows. The query will return one row if there's a match, or no rows if there's no match. So all you need to check is the number of matching rows in the database.

```
def Check(userName, Password):
    c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userInformation   WHERE userNames = ?",  
           (userName,))
    row = c.fetch()
    if row[0] > 0:
        login_screen()
    else:
        Create_Data_entry(userName, Password)
```

Comment: I think `row[0]` will cause an error if there are no rows returned by the query, as `row` will then be `[]`.

Comment: @LaurentS This query always returns exactly 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are several answers that all bring some info, I'll try to summarize what seems correct:

```
c.fetchall
```

[returns an empty iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) (empty list) if the `SELECT` query finds no match in the database.

In that case, your code is equivalent to:

```
for r in []:
    # this loop never gets executed and r is never assigned a value (as mentioned in another comment)
    print(r)
if row[0] == userName:  # at this point...
```

...you would get a `NameError: name 'row' is not defined` in the global scope, which is an `UnboundLocalError` [in the function scope](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html?highlight=unboundlocalerror#UnboundLocalError) instead.

For details on block scope, read [this section of the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding), in particular:

> When a name is not found at all, a NameError exception is raised. If the name refers to a local variable that has not been bound, a UnboundLocalError exception is raised. UnboundLocalError is a subclass of NameError.

**Original answer (wrong)**

Assuming your indentation is the same in your code, `row[0]` will cause the error.

Check your code carefully, you don't actually define the symbol before that.

The `for` loop defines the variable locally, but you then, outside the loop, try to assign one element of a list which is not defined before.

Comment: Python does not have block scope. Assuming the for loop ran, `row` would be defined.

Comment: I don't think accepting my wrong answer is fair, there are other, much better (and correct!) ones :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your `if row[0] == userName:` is outside your loop. So the variable `row` does not exist in this context.

You probably meant to put it inside your for loop.

As Daniel Roseman commented bellow, python doesn't have block scope variables, but if your look doesn't run at least once (the iterator is empty), then the block variable doesn't exist, which looks like to be your case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please fix your indentations. This snippet will definitely not run. Once that's fixed - it's all in your scoping. `row` only exists in your for loop when you're iterating over `R()`. As soon as you break out of the loop, that variable has no meaning. You would probably want something like this:

```
   def Check(userName, Password):  

       c.execute("SELECT userNames FROM userInformation   WHERE(userNames = ?)",  
               (userName,))    
       R = c.fetchall # Allow C.fetchall to populate other processes  
       for row in R():
           print(row)
           if row[0] == userName:  
               login_screen()  
           else:  
               Create_Data_entry(userName, Password)
```